# Using wildcards with "convert". Or "convert"ing a group of files

Tags: bash

I regularly scan in my Homework for class. My scanner exports raw jpg files to usb, and from there I can use gimp to edit and save the files as a pdf. One time saver I've found is to export my multi-page homeworks as a .mng file and then use the convert function to turn it into a pdf. I do it this way because Gimp automatically merges all layers when exporting to a pdf.

```
convert HW.mng HW.pdf
```

this works well for individual files, but at the end of every week I can have dozens of files to convert.

I have tried using wildcards in the filenames for convert:

```
convert *.mng *.pdf
```

This always runs successfully and never throws an error, but never produces any pdfs.

Both

```
convert HW*.mng HW*.pdf
```

and

```
convert "HW*.mng" "HW*.pdf"
```

yeild the error

```
convert: unable to open image `HW*.pdf': Invalid argument @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2712.
```

which I think means the error lies in exporting with a wildcard.

Is there any way to convert all of a specific file type to another using convert? Or should I try using a different program?

Comment: Try `mogrify -format pdf *mng` on some test files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see this [StackExchange](https://superuser.com/questions/660437/linux-run-command-on-a-batch-of-files-with-matching-output-files) post. The accepted answer basically does what you want.

`for file in *.mng; do convert -input "$file" -output "${file/%mng/pdf}"; done`

Answer (score 3):

For `convert` in particular, use `mogrify` ([which is part of ImageMagick as well](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/mogrify.php)) as suggested by Mark Setchell in a comment. `mogrify` can be used to edit/convert files in batches. The command for your case would be

```sh
mogrify -format pdf -- *.mng
```

Comment: It is worth noting that mogrify will overwrite the original files while convert does not. The OP may or may not want this.

Comment: @noah Generally, yes. However for `-format` there is an exception and it will create new files. The page I linked says: *[...] original image file is overwritten (unless you change the file suffix with the `-format` option)*